# Count the number of red pixels in an image with histc

Tags: histogram, octave, rgb

Ok, so I was assigned to make a function that returns a vector containing the number of red pixels in every bin from a given image. The function in Octave has this header:

function [n] = rHistogram(path_to_image, count_bins)

where path_to_image is literally the path to the image and count_bins is the number of bins. And I also have to utilize the "histc" function. Can you please help me with the code for this function, I don't know where to start from.

Comment: i addition to my answer below, please see:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions
try to expand your question with specifics as you develop your answer

Answer (score 0):

ok, since this sounds like a homework assignment we don't want to just give the answer now. Please feel free to update your question with 'what I've tried so far', especially just a 'step by step' outline of your plan for your function to work through the problem. It will help you guide yourself through the steps needed to solve the assignment.  Maybe later someone (maybe you) can come back and add an actual working answer, but here are some pointers:

1. what do you have to work with?  you have a path to an image file, and a bin count, and that's it.  If you knew nothing about the code, and didn't have to write code, how would you do this? Imagine you're looking at a physical mosaic, and had to sort the colored tiles into different buckets. you would look at each pixel, and based on it's characteristics, decide where it should go.
2. In code, you need to know - what is your image made of?  what ways can Octave look at an image just given it's filename? Once it finds it, how does Octave 'store' the image in memory.  hint - there's an array of numbers that will depend on the type of image.
3. Now, what details of that Octave-stored image can you use just like if you were sorting color tiles?  Probably something about the value. You'll need to go through each pixel (tile) and decide what to do with it.  What ways can Octave step through every pixel in the image? (there are probably multiple ways, some one at a time, others as big groups, but use what you can makes sense of. later you can learn more efficient ways.)  how can Octave 'compare' the color to decide where it should go?
4. What does 'where it should go' mean for a histogram? What do you imagine your output array should look like? How can you create something like that, and what does 'putting the tile in a bucket' do to that thing you need to create?

There are a lot of possible ways to tackle this problem.  There may even be some built in functions that shortcut tedious steps, like reading the image, sorting data, and creating a histogram, etc.  You'll need to be familiar with the programming language, and available algorithm structures.  A good hint is to start with small steps, and keep testing along the way. Learn to 'step' through your code watching the read, stored, and processed data change as you go.

Be sure to refer to the latest version of [the Octave manual](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/) where you can search for specific things.
Another advantage is that Octave has designed itself to be Matlab compatible (and it's probably 90% there if you don't need specialized tools), so you can search for help, suggestions, or code examples among both Octave and Matlab information on line.